# Trying to publish an Azure API. VS2017 doesn't seem to have the latest Azure SDK

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps, azure-sdk

I'm using Visual Studio 2017. I've developed a web API and I'm publishing it to Azure. The API isn't showing up in the Azure Portal, but it is in the Azure Resource Explorer. I did some research, and I found this article that says the the API is being published with an outdated Azure SDK.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/03/31/publishing-azure-api-app-and-it-does-not-appear-in-the-portal/

I'm using the latest vesion of VS 2017, 15.1 (26403.7).

I've verified my API is being published with the "apiapp" kind property. The article says the fix is to update my Azure SDK, but that seems to be integrated into the "Azure development" workload in VS2017. I don't see any way to force an update.

Is this a problem with Visual Studio 2017? Or, is there some other way to update the Azure SDK? Can I fix this in the Azure Resource Manager, until it's fixed?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: As you mentioned the release of the Azure SDK for .NET is built in to the Azure Workload. All the tools you need to do Azure development will be part of Visual Studio 2017 going forward.It works correctly on my side.   Do you have a try to uninstall and re-install the Azure development or  try to change the kind from 'apiapp' to 'api' with [azure resource](https://resources.azure.com).

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled the workload, and did a new publish profile. The resource explorer still shows it as "apiapp". I tried changing the "kind" property in the resource explorer, but it changes back. (I clicked the Edit button, changed "apiapp" to "api", and clicked Put. The resource explorer reports success.)

Comment: Are you publishing a dotnet Core application by any chance? There is a known bug with the latest tooling that causes dotnet Core apps to be incorrectly tagged when creating Azure API Apps.

Comment: I am! Is there a workaround?

Comment: Ah cool! The workaround is to create the API app in the portal first, then publish to it from Visual Studio.

Comment: Of course. That makes perfect sense. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug with the publishing profile for dotnet Core applications in the latest Azure SDK.

Creating an API App in the Azure portal and then publishing to it from Visual Studio should tag the app correctly.

Comment: Is there a link to the tracked issue anywhere? (GitHub? microsoft.com?)

Comment: I'm not aware of a publicly tracked issue for this fix, but we've pushed the fix for visibility, so there should be no functional limitations with creating dotnet Core API Apps through the VS SDK.